# How to Decide where Camera Shots are Going?

Tags: camera, 6.0-marshmallow

I cannot find any option in Settings of different Camera applications etc Nexus default Camera and CyanogenMod Camera where the pictures are going. 
I would like that new pictures go to the directory *SD://BTsync/Camera*. 
I am using Android 6 and CyanogenMod 13.

---

How can you change the default locations of new pictures from Camera?

Comment: AFAIK... on most stock camera apps, you can't. There's always a solution with [tag:automation] apps though.

Comment: @AndrewT. Is there any application which does allow us to decide the location?

Comment: @AndrewT. Is there any phone which allows it? I got today Oneplus 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew's answer in comment

> AFAIK... on most stock camera apps, you can't. There's always a solution with automation apps though. – Andrew T. Mar 16 '16 at 9:54